# Move table to another with Primary Key

Tags: ios, sqlite, integer, copy

I made table in .sql database file. Column for integer was created but by mistake it wasn't set as primary key. Now I wanted to fix it by creating new table where id table was set this time as Primary Key. When tried to copy data from one table to another always getting error as long as new table contains column with primary key. It's very important for me so I'm asking for any help.

```
[self openDB];

sqlite3_stmt *statement3;
if(sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *tableName=@"bookings2";

    NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"create table %@(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, testBooking TEXT, timeFrom TEXT, timeTo TEXT, pupilName TEXT, description TEXT, date_of_event TEXT, lessonBooked TEXT, pupilId TEXT)",tableName];
    const char *update_stmt = [query UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, update_stmt, -1, &statement3, NULL);

    if(sqlite3_step(statement3)==SQLITE_DONE)

        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(statement3);
    sqlite3_close(db);
}


[self openDB];

NSString *strSqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO bookings2 (testBooking, timeFrom, timeTo, pupilName, description, date_of_event, pupilId, lessonBooked) SELECT testBooking, timeFrom, timeTo, pupilName, description, date_of_event, pupilId, lessonBooked FROM bookings"];


char *err;
if (sqlite3_exec(db, [strSqlStatement UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) !=SQLITE_OK)
{
    sqlite3_close(db);
    NSAssert(0, @"Couldn't create table");
}else {
    sqlite3_close(db);
    NSLog(@"done");
}
```

Comment: In the absence of code, we can only guess, but I wonder if your source table is missing this numeric key or it's not unique. Share code and sample of the data, or else this question will likely be closed.

Comment: Edited question already. It's code I would use.

Comment: Excellent. I'd suggest that where you log "Couldn't create table" that you also include `sqlite3_errmsg`, e.g. `NSAssert(0, @"Couldn't create table: %s", sqlite_errmsg(db));`. If you do that, SQLite will provide a clue as to precisely what the error was.

Comment: in my situation it says: "library routine called out of sequence"

Comment: My bad. That error usually means that the database was closed by the time you got to the SQLite call. Make sure you do `sqlite3_errmsg` before you close the database. You probably should just `NSLog` the `sqlite3_errmsg` before you perform your `sqlite3_close` and `NSAssert`.

Comment: I was always trying similar ways yesterday but today addind [self openDB] between queries solved problem. Maybe I did Autoincrement without it yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

When you define the column `id`, you should also include `AUTOINCREMENT`. This way, it will automatically supply each `id` value a unique integer value.

```
NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"create table %@(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, testBooking TEXT, timeFrom TEXT, timeTo TEXT, pupilName TEXT, description TEXT, date_of_event TEXT, lessonBooked TEXT, pupilId TEXT)", tableName];
```

And, as general counsel, I'd encourage you to always log `sqlite3_errmsg` (or if you passed a pointer to your own `char *err`, look at that) if your SQLite code doesn't behave as expected. The error messages returned are generally quite illuminating.

Comment: You definitely need `AUTOINCREMENT` if you're not inserting the `id` values yourself. I bet there's some other issue going on in addition to the missing `AUTOINCREMENT`.

Answer (score 0):

This is working code:

```
-(void)fixDiary {



[self openDB];


//////// add column if it not exist
sqlite3_stmt *statement3;
if(sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *tableName=@"bookings2";

    NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"create table %@(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, testBooking TEXT, timeFrom TEXT, timeTo TEXT, pupilName TEXT, description TEXT, date_of_event TEXT, lessonBooked TEXT, pupilId TEXT)", tableName];



    const char *update_stmt = [query UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, update_stmt, -1, &statement3, NULL);

    if(sqlite3_step(statement3)==SQLITE_DONE)

        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(statement3);
    sqlite3_close(db);
}

[self openDB];


// Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
NSString *strSqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO bookings2 (testBooking, timeFrom, timeTo, pupilName, description, date_of_event, pupilId, lessonBooked) SELECT testBooking, timeFrom, timeTo, pupilName, description, date_of_event, pupilId, lessonBooked FROM bookings"];


char *err;
if (sqlite3_exec(db, [strSqlStatement UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) !=SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSAssert(0, @"Couldn't create table: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_close(db);
}else {
    NSLog(@"done");
}
```

}